# Remove "Your Own" wording from a new site proposed in Area 51

Tags: feature-request, area-51, user-interface, wording

### At the end of [Stack Exchange sites page](https://stackexchange.com/sites) it is mentioned:

[image: Want to start your own Stack Exchange Q&A site? Check out Area 51. Our friendly robots are waiting.]

I know there are many ways of interpreting "own" as like mentioned by [Shadow The Kid Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-the-kid-wizard) over [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9356157#9356157):

> Single user can propose a new site. So "your own" makes perfect sense.

However naturally "your own" feels more like you are the owner of the Stack Exchange Site you are proposing in [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com). While technically "your own" is right in the sense that you are the founder of the site as you were the first one to propose it however "your own" feels more of like once that sites get released from Area 51 you are the owner of the site. In my opinion I feel the wording should be changed to

> Want to propose a new site? Check out [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com). Our friendly robots are waiting.

Or something better?

Comment: I agree the wording should be changed, but I think your alternative proposal has its own problems. Considering you're not supposed to start an Area 51 proposal before you got a community around the topic going on (people ignoring this is a major cause for most of the proposals failing), we could probably reword it to include that. Technically, if you can't find an SE for any topic, you're searching wrong. What you want to ask is whether they found an SE for the topic they're interested in.

Comment: @Mast Well if correctly searching gives you an SE site for each topic then why do we even have Area51 right now?

Comment: Considering we already have 181 sites as part of the SE network, asking why we even have Area51 right now is a good question. However, that would be a different question than the one you're asking now.

Comment: @Mast There is no already existing site for "Crytocurrency" so for such site topics we have Area 51. However I have changed my proposed wording to a much simpler one as the simpler one would be more better and accurate.

Comment: @JitendraSingh did you choose Cryptocurrency randomly? Because there is a [recent proposal](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/127389/cryptocurrency).

Comment: I think your new alternative is much better than the previous one.

Comment: I imagine that the first sentence of the old line was written back in the Stack Exchange 1.0 days, when people would indeed start their own sites by paying SE a fee. Then the subsequent sentences got changed, but not the first one.